# Its possible to load "Image Formatter" on a theme?

Tags: theming, 8

I'm building a Drupal 8 theme, and I need the functionality of [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter). I do not want to have a contrib module as dependency of my theme. So I started digging up into the [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) code and I notice that it was very simple module. For this reason, I try to stole that code and added into my theme and I'm not able to see the image formatter =(.

Then I notice that DrupalConsole have generator to generate the same functionality from [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) (the generator have like 95% of the same code as IUM), so I decide to added into my theme and for some reason did not run.

The location of my code is at - **Casper/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/CasperImageFormatter.php**
and the source code is the same as what the generator provide, which is...

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\casper\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\CasperImageFormatter.
 */

namespace Drupal\casper\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

use Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\ImageFormatterBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Utility\LinkGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'casper_image_formatter' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "casper_image_formatter",
 *   label = @Translation("Casper image formatter"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "image"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class CasperImageFormatter extends ImageFormatterBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {
    /**
     * The current user.
     *
     * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface
     */
    protected $currentUser;

    /**
     * The link generator.
     *
     * @var \Drupal\Core\Utility\LinkGeneratorInterface
     */
    protected $linkGenerator;

    /**
     * The image style entity storage.
     *
     * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface
     */
    protected $imageStyleStorage;

    /**
     * Constructs an ImageFormatter object.
     *
     * @param string $plugin_id
     *   The plugin_id for the formatter.
     * @param mixed $plugin_definition
     *   The plugin implementation definition.
     * @param \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition
     *   The definition of the field to which the formatter is associated.
     * @param array $settings
     *   The formatter settings.
     * @param string $label
     *   The formatter label display setting.
     * @param string $view_mode
     *   The view mode.
     * @param array $third_party_settings
     *   Any third party settings settings.
     * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $current_user
     *   The current user.
     * @param \Drupal\Core\Utility\LinkGeneratorInterface $link_generator
     *   The link generator service.
     * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface $image_style_storage
     *   The entity storage for the image.
     */
    public function __construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, array $settings, $label, $view_mode, array $third_party_settings, AccountInterface $current_user, LinkGeneratorInterface $link_generator, EntityStorageInterface $image_style_storage) {
        parent::__construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $field_definition, $settings, $label, $view_mode, $third_party_settings);
        $this->currentUser = $current_user;
        $this->linkGenerator = $link_generator;
        $this->imageStyleStorage = $image_style_storage;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
        return new static(
            $plugin_id,
            $plugin_definition,
            $configuration['field_definition'],
            $configuration['settings'],
            $configuration['label'],
            $configuration['view_mode'],
            $configuration['third_party_settings'],
            $container->get('current_user'),
            $container->get('link_generator'),
            $container->get('entity.manager')->getStorage('image_style')
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function defaultSettings() {
        return array(
            'image_style' => '',
            'image_link' => '',
        ) + parent::defaultSettings();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function settingsForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $image_styles = image_style_options(FALSE);
        $element['image_style'] = array(
            '#title' => t('Image style'),
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#default_value' => $this->getSetting('image_style'),
            '#empty_option' => t('None (original image)'),
            '#options' => $image_styles,
            '#description' => array(
                '#markup' => $this->linkGenerator->generate($this->t('Configure Image Styles'), new Url('entity.image_style.collection')),
                '#access' => $this->currentUser->hasPermission('administer image styles'),
            ),
        );

        return $element;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function settingsSummary() {
        $summary = array();
        $image_styles = image_style_options(FALSE);

        // Unset possible 'No defined styles' option.
        unset($image_styles['']);

        // Styles could be lost because of enabled/disabled modules that defines
        // their styles in code.
        $image_style_setting = $this->getSetting('image_style');
        if (isset($image_styles[$image_style_setting])) {
            $summary[] = t('Image style: @style', array('@style' => $image_styles[$image_style_setting]));
        }
        else {
            $summary[] = t('Original image');
        }

        return $summary;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
        $elements = array();
        $files = $this->getEntitiesToView($items, $langcode);

        // Early opt-out if the field is empty.
        if (empty($files)) {
            return $elements;
        }

        $url = NULL;
        $image_link_setting = $this->getSetting('image_link');
        // Check if the formatter involves a link.
        if ($image_link_setting == 'content') {
            $entity = $items->getEntity();
            if (!$entity->isNew()) {
                $url = $entity->urlInfo();
            }
        }
        elseif ($image_link_setting == 'file') {
            $link_file = TRUE;
        }

        $image_style_setting = $this->getSetting('image_style');

        // Collect cache tags to be added for each item in the field.
        $cache_tags = array();
        if (!empty($image_style_setting)) {
            $image_style = $this->imageStyleStorage->load($image_style_setting);
            $cache_tags = $image_style->getCacheTags();
        }

        foreach ($files as $delta => $file) {
            if (isset($link_file)) {
                $image_uri = $file->getFileUri();
                $url = Url::fromUri(file_create_url($image_uri));
            }

            $cache_tags = Cache::mergeTags($cache_tags, $file->getCacheTags());

            // Extract field item attributes for the theme function, and unset them
            // from the $item so that the field template does not re-render them.
            $item = $file->_referringItem;
            $item_attributes = $item->_attributes;
            unset($item->_attributes);

            $elements[$delta] = array(
                '#theme' => 'image_formatter',
                '#item' => $item,
                '#item_attributes' => $item_attributes,
                '#image_style' => $image_style_setting,
                '#url' => $url,
                '#cache' => array(
                    'tags' => $cache_tags,
                ),
            );
        }

        return $elements;
    }

}
```

I was able to run the same code into a module and it works perfect, but for some reason when I try to run it into the theme it does not work.

My question is...

- Its possible to run this much logic into my theme, if so what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs for plugins](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/plugins), you'll see this:

> Plugins are defined by modules: a module may provide plugins of different types, and different modules may provide their own plugins of a particular type.

While it doesn't explicitly exclude themes, I think you can infer from that phrase that only modules can provide plugins.

An option would be to structure your theme's code to be aware of the existence of a module, and react differently, e.g.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_foo(&$vars) {  
  if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('image_url_formatter')) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to have the module as dependency. Instead I want to add the module functionality with in my theme. I do not know if this change your answer.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately - themes can't define plugins, only modules can. To define a formatter plugin you'll need a module, no exceptions as far as I can tell

Comment: Looking at the bootstrap theme, it seem like they are using plugins. http://i.imgur.com/dKaz6uH.png. Maybe those are good OOP structure and not real plugins ?

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure, maybe I'm wrong. Let me have a look around and see what's happening there

Comment: I think the key is how [`FormatterPluginManager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FormatterPluginManager.php/class/FormatterPluginManager/8)'s discovery works. Maybe it's not considering themes? I'm popping out now will try to come back and have a better look later

Comment: By default, plugin managers do not support plugins in themes. You can't change that. Use a module.

Comment: Yeah, what @Berdir said. The authors of the bootstrap theme have implemented their own plugin system, based on core's, but it's not integrated with core's.